# Java Stackoverflow

Tags: java, recursion, stack, stack-overflow

I created an application to intentionally trigger `StackOverflowError`s, and it is exhibiting some strange behavior.  My application relies on a recursive method, and this method has a base case for terminating the recursion: it increments a variable in a `while` loop until its value equals or exceeds a hardcoded target value.  The strange behavior is that the minimum target value necessary to trigger a stack overflow is not consistent from run to run.  Why might that be?

Here's the code:

```
public class MyClass {
    private static MyClass appOne4 = new MyClass();
    private static int i = 0;

    public void causeStackoverflowException() {//Recursive Method
        System.out.println(i);
        while (i<12000) {
            i++; //This works since variable "i" is static
            causeStackoverflowException();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        appOne4.causeStackoverflowException();
    }
}
```

Updated Code

```
public class MyClass {
    private static MyClass appOne4 = new MyClass();
    private static int i = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        appOne4.causeStackoverflowException(i);
    }

    public int causeStackoverflowException(int myI) {//Recursive Method
        System.out.println(myI);
        if(myI==10460) {//12000
            return myI;
        }
        if (myI<12000) {
            myI++; //This works since variable "i" is static
            return causeStackoverflowException(myI);
        }
        return -1;////ERROR
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried to profile the runs?

Comment: Try to run it from the command line - I'm sure you'll get the overflow for the same value again and again. The IDE is allocating memory dynamically and even if you quit it, it still remembers the last values it used.

Comment: @efektive Ok. I did not know about Java profiling until now :) I am kind of new to Java. Would you say "JVM Monitor" for Eclipse is a ok tool for this purpose? Thanks :)

Comment: @TDG why it should be object allocation? there is no such, one can think of only println call. The exception is clearly StackOverflow -> stack cannot fit all the method return references.

Comment: Note that your `while` loop is a pointless distraction.  In no invocation of `causeStackOverflowException()` will more than one iteration of that loop be performed, because if the recursive invocation does not throw an error then after it returns, `i` is certain to have been incremented to the target value.  It would be better to simplify by changing to an `if` statement (though I do not expect that to alter the observed behavior).

Comment: @chromechris you cannot predict how much space on the stack you have exactly only for your method calls.

Comment: @TDG I assume you meant JVM instead of IDE. In that case, I ran it from CMD and indeed, the same behavior is observed.

Comment: visualjvm is what I have used, not that hard to use but there are others. A simple search would yield several

Comment: @efektive Cool, thanks! :)

Comment: @John Bollinger Thanks for pointing that out :) I will update the code in the question.